# Script Tag Error - Aura Lightning Component

Tags: aura

I am able to include a JS file as static resource in my lightning component.
But when I add "<<'script'>>" tag in the JS file it gives an error.

I want script tag as i need to use src attribute in the JS file and then call it through static resource in my lightning component

JS Code

Comment: Welcome to the SE community it is always better to post your existing code while asking the question. it will avoid extra conversation and you will get specific answer in timely manner. You can go through the help section to understand how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

script tag is not supported into in lightning component so you need to use ltng:require to include script from static resource in following way

```
<ltng:require scripts='/resource/path/to/js1.js,/resource/path/to/js2.js'/>
```

Note: SFDC don't allow to put inline script tag so only option is to move javascript code insdie controller.js or load from external javascript as shown above.

Comment: Yes I used the above code and included the JS file ,

In the JS file i need to add script src = "my code"

Comment: do you see any error? post your lightning component code here.

Comment: Syntax error for "<"
Basically it doesnt allow script tag in JS file

Comment: update this question with your complete component code. I am not getting what you are referring here.

Comment: <aura:application>
<ltng:require scripts="/resource/Test"  />
</aura:application>

JS Code
<script src="//test.com/test.js"></script>

Comment: as i said earlier script tag is not allowed in lightning component, it means you can't write inline script. So move your script inside the controller.js file or load from external javascript as shown above.

Comment: Agreed Himashu ,
I have moved the script tag to extenal file and loaded it through ltng:require
Is that also not allowed?

Comment: you can upvote the answer and close it.

Comment: I have moved the script tag to extenal file and loaded it through ltng:require Is that also not allowed?

Comment: Or In controller.js can I call another JS file?

Comment: that is allowed. there is no need to put script tag there. as that is external script you can directly put your code into that file.  You can't call JS file in controller.js but you can call any function from that file in controller.js

Comment: In the external file I want to redirect to another source - So I mentioned in the external file 

<script src="//test.com/test.js"></script

I want to use the source (src) tag in the external file , without the script tag i cannot use the src attribute. 

Hope you got my question now

Comment: please go through the document to understand how script work in lighting https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_libs_platform.htm

Comment: I have already gone through those links , Couldnt find any solution so posted here.

Basically , In the external file I want Javascript src attribute to link to another .js file. ----script src = "test.com/test.js"----

But external file does not allow script tag,

How do I achieve that?

Comment: i am unable to understand why you want to put another js file in your external. you can put them as defined in answer and they will load in sequential manner and it is equivalent to loading js with src attribute. if you want to refer any external js file (from CDN etc) which is not uploaded in static resource you can't refer that in lighting component.

Comment: actually need to refer to the external js file from a website --- which you are saying will not be possible in lightning component through static resource -- right?

Comment: that is correct. you can't refer any external js file inside lightning component. only static resources are allowed.