# Translating Visualforce Page to Lightning Component (Where to put <script> tags?)

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, javascript

I have many  tags in my visualforce page, and am attempting to translate it to a lightning component. My  tags are necessary because I need Kendo templates wrapped in script tags.

I got an error saying I can't have script tags in the component, so I moved all of my javascript to the Controller, and it says invalid character '<', which is referencing the '<' on .

Am I not able to just throw all of my Javascript (there is a lot......) into the controller and have it function correctly? If not, how do you include  tags in a lightning component? Where do you put them?

Comment: you cannot use script tags in lightning components. and no, you cannot throw all your code in a controller and expect it to work. I would strongly recommend you do the basic lightning component Trailheads in order to familiarize yourself with the aura framework

Comment: Can you use <script> tags anywhere? In the controller/helper/renderer?

Comment: That post didn't answer my question. That tells you how to add an external script. I have templates that are wrapped in <script> tags that are inline, they can't be static resources.

Comment: the answer to your question is in the first comment, and the answer to the duplicate cleaarly states, script tags are nto supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is: nowhere (as glls explained in his first coment). There is nowhere, in any of the files associated with a lightning component bundle, that  tags can be placed. If you attempt to you'll get an error.

This is from the lightning
From Trailhead on Lightning Components:

> While it’s possible to use third-party JavaScript frameworks with
>   Lightning Components, it’s a bit cumbersome. Lightning Components
>   doesn’t have the notion of an empty page, and has some specific
>   opinions about how, for example, data access is performed, and some
>   rather specific security requirements.
>
> And frankly, the features of Lightning Components and most modern
>   frameworks overlap quite a bit. While the style or specifics might be
>   different, the features provided are conceptually similar enough that
>   you’re effectively running duplicate code. That’s neither efficient
>   nor easy to work with.
>
> Another thing to consider: general-purpose frameworks such as
>   AngularJS are designed to be agnostic about the platform they run on
>   top of, in particular data services. Lightning Components, on the
>   other hand, is designed to connect natively with services provided by
>   Salesforce and the Force.com platform. Which do you think is going to
>   help you build apps faster?

Basically, you really shouldn't be using any frameworks or complicated JavaScript libraries in lightning components. SFDC has already built most of what you'll need to accomplish your goals.

This question has been answered in [other posts](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/98212/script-tag-error-aura-lightning-component) on this site as well.

Comment: Even if I were to put my <script> tag templates in a static resource, loaded in that static resource, and appended them to the body of the lightning component, it will error? If so, then Lightning Components will not work for me. I have a Kendo UI Scheduler we were interested in changing to a Lightning Component from a VF page... which requires complicated external JS libraries (the kendo libraries) and the <script> template tags. It may just have to stay a VF page.

Comment: I'm not sure if doing that would work or not, I've never had a need to try. Lightning components are not loaded in frames the way VF is so you'd be accessing the actual page including all the HTML and javascript provided by SF which could very likely cause errors (for instance, both jQuery and Salesforce have libraries that use the $ character as a function name which causes conflicts). It's possible that if you tried you'd run into unpredictable conflicts.

Comment: You can choose not to switch to lightning now just to maintain your kendo UI scheduler, but sfdc is moving the way of lightning and chances are you'll be forced to switch eventually.  You're running a huge gamble building your entire career around Kendo. Lightning will work for you, you just have to put some effort into re-making your scheduler. This is one of the many many reasons I don't recommend complicated UI's in Salesforce. They are always a waste of time and money.

Comment: My solution is a custom JavaScript solution. It actually doesn't utilize the "outdated" look of visual force. It just lives on a visualforce page. I was attempting a lightning component because for some reason, slds is not being loaded in the salesforce1 app/emulator, even though it is in my head. I was hoping having it as a lightning component would automatically include such styling, but not sure that will work. It won't work if I can't load in kendo templates...